# Get records between two point values in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two columns that store values(point values).

How do I select where my given number is between the values in the two columns ?

Comment: `where number >= col1 and number <= col2` - does it not wrok?

Comment: where number bettween col1 and col2..

Comment: Ya thats not working because i am using values are like that 10.7904833

Comment: from column1 6.7535159 and column2 35.5087008

Comment: you must shoiw us what you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can get it by doing this:

Lets your number is $your_number and table name is your_table

So your query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE $your_number BETWEEN col1 AND col2;
```

Or if it is ensured that col1 < col2

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE $your_number >= col1 AND $your_number <= col2;
```

Comment: @chitra does my answer not working from you? If your question like this then it should work. Otherwise edit your question.